# Creating Dynamic refs in React outside constructor

Tags: reactjs, ref

I am creating multiple textfields based on the number of elements I receive from an API call that returns an array.

To access these values I need refs and I cannot create the refs inside the constructor since I won't even know the number of textfields when the component is loaded.

My question is how do I create the refs like the one below

```
this[myinputboxname] = React.createRef();
```

Once I receive the API result

Comment: If you don't even know the amount of refs you need, seems that you should use a dynamically sized data structure, such as Array

Answer (score 0):

It is not mandatory to create a ref inside constructor. It can be created on the fly as following.

```
<component
ref={(comp) => {this[`comp-${id}`] = comp}}
/>
```